# Using the face edit mode as a texture in bge

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv, faces

In the blender game engine, is it possible to make it look like this when you actually play the game?
[image]

Obviously, this was screenshotted outside of the game player while in edit mode, so maybe it's possible to bake this texture to an actual texture which I can apply to a material?
This is very likely impossible though, so maybe theres a script someone made to generate the texture for each face? (so for each face just a simple light grey texture with dark grey outlines?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have arrived at an imperfect approximation. It will create the effect, but has some flaws:

- Edge lines will be inconsistently thick.
- Center point may not be exactly centered.

However, the result is definitely passable:

[image]

To create this, you need a few steps:

1. UV unwrap it. You <kbd>U</kbd>>*UV unwrap*
2. Reset the UV's <kbd>U</kbd>>*Reset*
3. Add an image texture, I used this image:

[image]

4. Set the UV map

TADA! You have your result!

See the .blend for any confusing details:

[image]

Comment: I was going to do this method, but I did not add my answer because it does not work on non-rectangular faces.

Comment: @X-27 That is a drawback, but I figured this is better then nothing...